# Access files from Linux virtual box on Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, virtualbox

On my machine I run Windows7, now I installed the virtual box and in virtual box I put Ubuntu 14.04. On Linux I installed LAMP. Now, I want to access the folder `/var/www` from Linux (virtual box) on my Windows 7 machine.

In virtual box network the configuration is: *Host-only Adapter*. The idea is that I want to access this folder by creating a *Mapped Network Drive*. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `nfs` to share your folders to Windows. If it works, `samba` will also be a good option to go with. Make sure you're able to ping the VM which you most probably will be able to. Share your folder via NFS/Samba and I think you can share the folder.

Otherwise, you can also share the folder in Windows via the GUI that Virtualbox provides, install Virtualbox Guest Addition package and mount the shared windows folder as `vboxsf` type, via which you can share transfer and access files across both the operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `bridged adapter` in your virtual machine? by doing this is just like you have an additional host in your network.